# What's wrong with this Ruby program that counts vowels?

Tags: ruby, string, count

When I test this program on strings the output is 0. I think my logic is sound and it's just a minor syntax thing. Anyone see the problem?

```
def VowelCount(string)

  string.downcase
  i = 0
  vowels = 0

  until i == string.length-1
    if (string[i] == "a" || string[i] == "o" || string[i] == "e" || string[i] == "i" || string[i] == "u")
      vowels += 1
      end
    i += 1
    end
  return vowels
  end
```

Comment: Method names in Ruby are snake_case, `VowelCount` should be `vowel_count`.

Comment: One thing to consider is that if you're using strings with capitalized vowels, it will miss them. The line `string.downcase` creates and then discards a lowercase string. If you want to modify `string` itself, you need `string.downcase!` or `string = string.downcase`.

Comment: Here are a couple of more economical ways to write your `if` statement: 1) `if ("aeiou".include?(string[i])); ...; end` and 2) `case string[i]; when 'a','e','i','o','u'; ... end`.

Answer (score 5):

You can use [String#count](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.3/String.html#method-i-count):

```
str = "It was the best of times, it was the worst of times,..."

str.downcase.count('aeiou') #=> 14
```

Comment: Yes, I know. It's easy to do. :-)

Answer (score 3):

The following line

```
until i == string.length-1
```

should be:

```
until i == string.length
```

Otherwise, the last character is not checked.

BTW, by convension, method name starts with lower case, and combined with underscore. Here's an alternative solution using regular expression.

```
def vowel_count(string)
  string.scan(/[aeiou]/i).length
end
```

**update**

As JesseSielaff pointed, String#downcase does not change the string in place. You need to assign the return value of the method back or use String.downcase!

Comment: But indexes start at 0, so string.length references a non-existant character in the string. Right?

Comment: @DavidCharles, The predicate is checked before the loop body is executed.

Comment: @DavidCharles, Try `VowelCount('hello')`. It should return 2, but with the wrong predicate, it returns 1.

Comment: By predicate you mean "until i == string.length", right? That makes sense now -- because once i == string.length, the loop body will not be run and thus the program will never try to access string[string.length].

Comment: @DavidCharles, The predicate means `i == string.length` part.

Comment: When I call this method, I still get "0". Any idea why?

Comment: @DavidCharles, It works for me. See http://ideone.com/EdlOWY  Make sure you are calling the function with correct string?

Comment: I see that.. the only difference is that I'm using repl.it. I see there's a "p" in front of the method when you call it, when I try that I still end up with an output of 0.

Comment: repl.it uses Ruby 1.8. In this version of Ruby string[i] returns an integer, so the comparisons always evaluate to false. Since Ruby 1.9 string[i] returns a string.

Comment: @DirkGrappendorf that's crazy annoying. Do you know of another ide that uses 1.9?

Comment: Replace "a" with ?a  to maje it work in 1.8.x and higher version.

Comment: @falsetru Thank you SO much! And thanks to everyone else who pitched in. #SatNightCoderClub